# Can't save and load plist file

Tags: ios, plist, xcode6, nsfilemanager

When i tried to create plist file('Checklist.plist') using following methods i can't see the file in the directory.
[image]

```
- (NSString *)documentsDirectory {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
return documentsDirectory; }

- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
return [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Checklists.plist"];
}
```

Why i can't see the file on the directory? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't see"? Are you sure the creation of the file succeeded (returned no error)? Are you looking in the right place on the simulator filesystem?

Comment: those methods don't create anything... show us where you write the file

Comment: I haven't seen any error message when i run the program.Yeah.I had tried to look the file using Similator filesystem. #Ben

Comment: I have updated the screenshot.You can see that Checklist.plist file has created on the disk.But when i go to the directory i can't see any file and even i can't see the Documentation directory under Library folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you save something in the file?

```
NSString *test = @"test";
[test writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

If you run this in a simulator, you can NSlog this file path, and than open finder, press `cmd + shift + g` paste the file path, don't include `Checklist.plist`, just documents file path, you will see the file you just create named `Checklist.plist`.

This is all my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSArray *testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", nil];
    [testArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
- (NSString *)documentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
    return documentsDirectory; 
}

- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    return [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Checklists.plist"];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Yeap.I had saved some objects in the plist file.I had followed every possible way you mentioned but isn't working.

Comment: Thank you.It worked! Can you please explain why the problem happened?

Comment: @MdRiduan Because you must save something to the file, than it will create it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The file isn't created when -dataFilePath is called.

To write a plain string in your file, use:

```
NSError *e = nil;
[@"blabla" writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];

NSError *e1 = nil;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e1];
```

Both errors should be nil and fileContents should contain the original string.